# Pegar posições excedentes de um array após comparação com outro array?

Tags: javascript, array, email, mongodb, comparação

Tenho uma função(em JavaScript) que compara 2 arrays:

```
let diferencas = [];
    let numD = 0;
    for (let a = 0; a < dados.length; a++) {
        if (dados[a].idEmail === results[a].idEmail) {
            console.log('Repetido!')
        } else {
            numD++;
            diferencas.push(dados[a]);
        }
    }
    console.log('Diferenças encontradas: ' + numD)
    console.log(diferencas)
```

Os 2 arrays são compostos em suas primeiras 8 posições por objetos idênticos, sendo que o array `results` possui somente 8 posições pois ele vem de uma consulta ao MongoDB e o array `dados` possui 9 posições, pois ele vem de uma consulta ao provedor de emails e vem com emails mais recentes.

O meu problema é: **Como Faço para pegar aquelas posições excedentes no array** `dados` **??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução ao problema em si é utilizando o `filter`, assim:

```
let diferencas = dados.filter(x => results.indexOf(x) ==-1 ? x : false );
```

Em que o `filter` parte do array `dados` que é o maior, e filtra verificando se cada elemento existe no `results` através do `indexOf`. Se o elemento corrente de `dados` não existir em `results` é devolvido `x` e por isso aparece nas `diferencas`. Caso contrario devolve `false` e exclui das `diferencas`

Exemplo:

```js
const dados = ['a@a.com','b@b.com','c@c.com','d@d.com', 'e@e.com'];
const results = ['a@a.com','b@b.com','c@c.com','d@d.com'];

let diferencas = dados.filter(x => results.indexOf(x) == -1 ? x:false);

console.log('Diferenças encontradas: ' + diferencas.length);
console.log(diferencas);
```

Se tiver um array de objetos continua a poder utilizar esta solução mas tem que aplicar um passo adicional para ficar apenas com os emails, que é primeiro mapear o array para um array de strings com os emails, utilizando o `map` e depois efetuar o mesmo procedimento:

```js
const dados = [
{email : 'a@a.com'},
{email : 'b@b.com'},
{email : 'c@c.com'},
{email : 'd@d.com'},
{email : 'e@e.com'}
];

const results = [
{email : 'a@a.com'},
{email : 'b@b.com'},
{email : 'c@c.com'},
{email : 'd@d.com'}
];

const dados2 = dados.map(x => x.email); //mapeamento aqui
const results2 = results.map(x => x.email);//mapeamento aqui

//o resto igual
let diferencas = dados2.filter(x => results2.indexOf(x)==-1?x:false);

console.log('Diferenças encontradas: ' + diferencas.length);
console.log(diferencas);

//Para diferenças em formato de objeto pode-se utilizar o map do diferencas para dados
let diferencasObj = diferencas.map(x => dados[dados2.indexOf(x)]);
console.log(diferencasObj);
```

Comparando com a solução que tem esta tem a vantagem de também funcionar mesmo se a ordem dos arrays não for igual.

Exemplo:

```js
const dados = ['b@b.com','c@c.com', 'e@e.com','a@a.com','d@d.com']; //desordenado
const results = ['d@d.com','a@a.com','b@b.com','c@c.com',]; //desordenado

let diferencas = dados.filter(x => results.indexOf(x) == -1 ? x:false);

console.log('Diferenças encontradas: ' + diferencas.length);
console.log(diferencas);
```

Comment: Aquele exemplo de arrays de objetos também traz somente a diferença independente da ordem dos objetos??

Comment: @LeonardoEbert Sim, apenas exemplifiquei com o array de strings para ser mais simples.

Comment: Estou fazendo uns testes aqui, porém ele não está identificando as diferenças... Vou colocar o código todo num jsfiddle e ja te mando o link

Comment: Está aqui o código inteiro: https://jsfiddle.net/70ebprun/

Não estou entendendo porque não está funcionando, pois testei com os exemplos acima e funcionou...

Comment: O mapeamento tem de ser ajustado ao seu exemplo, de `const dados2 = dados.map(x => x.email);` para `const dados2 = dados.map(x => x.idEmail);`. Atente na diferença entre `.email` para `.idEmail`. Eu na resposta exemplifiquei com campo `email` para que fosse mais claro ao leitor

Comment: Kkkkkkk, não vi essa diferença
Agora achou 3 diferenças...
Muito obrigado @Isac, você deu a solução perfeita para o meu problema

Comment: Só vou precisar agora adaptar para salvar os todos os dados dos objetos no banco de dados

Comment: @LeonardoEbert editei também para esse pormenor. Mas seria teria que remapear de novo com `map` para ter as diferenças em formato de objetos `let diferencasObj = diferencas.map(x => dados[dados2.indexOf(x)]);`

Comment: Essa sua última edição funcionou perfeitamente também, agora é só salvar os objetos diferentes no banco de dados

Answer (score 1):

Basta verificar se `results` existe, caso não exista `dados` excedeu...

```js
var dados = [
{idEmail : '1'},
{idEmail : '2'},
{idEmail : '3'},
{idEmail : '4'},
{idEmail : '5'},
];

var results = [
{idEmail : '1'},
{idEmail : '2'},
{idEmail : '3'},
{idEmail : '4'},
];

let diferencas = [];
    let numD = 0;
    for (let a = 0; a < dados.length; a++) {
        if (results[a]){
         if(dados[a].idEmail === results[a].idEmail) {
            console.log('Repetido!')
        }}else {
            numD++;
            diferencas.push(dados[a]);
        }
    }
    console.log('Diferenças encontradas: ' + numD);
    console.log(diferencas);
```

Comment: Excelente, funcionou 100%, muito obrigado @Felipe Duarte, já estava nesse problema há 2 dias... ; )

Comment: Normal kkk, javascript é isso mesmo.